# How to use mozc-jp in budgie?

Tags: 18.04, language-support, input-language, budgie

I know in normal ubuntu when you have mozc-jp installed you click on it in the top panel to change between hiragana and katakana etc but that icon doesn't exist on budgie so how do I do it thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Open `ibus-setup` and check the "Show icon on system tray" option. Add Mozc via `ibus-setup` and use the IBus icon to access the Mozc settings.

I submitted a couple of comments on [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1755831) which might add some info.

Answer (score 0):

Open `ibus-setup`, check "Show icon on system tray", click on tab "Input Method", add mozc there.

Then, open Budgie Desktop Settings, click "Panel", add applet, "System Tray". Now the ibus system tray icon will be shown, you can change keyboard layout to mozc there.